# Getting current user information from CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

How do you access information about the current user when navigating an app with a CouchDB database?  I need this information to query the correct data for each request, etc.  For example, in Rails it is common to use a before filter that sets a variable called current_user with every request.

After successfully initiating a session with a POST to /_session, I tried the following as suggested by the CouchDB docs, but it does not return the full user document with email and the other fields I need.

```
GET /_session
```

I also tried requesting the user document by id as follows but I am getting an error.

```
GET /_users/org.couch.user:<name>
```

Error:

```
{ error: not_found, reason: missing }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you are doing is correct. Just make sure that the <name> is the same person for whom you already created a session previously. For ex: if you made a post request to session for a person `corey` use this url `/_users/org.couch.user:<name>`. The error you are getting could be due to 2 reasons 1) The user does not exist. 2) The person does not have sufficient privileges to view it's details. An admin can view all the users. Where as a user can only view their own data.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I combined the two requests to get the full user document for the current user.

Comment: In CouchDB 3. I'm unable to fetch it anymore. Maybe because in Permissions of the _users database only _admin is allowed to access. And users can be added by admins as well. So, it is not really a user's own document. So I see the only way is to fetch it via middleware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working by combining the two requests as follows:

GET '/_session'

GET '/_users/org.couch.user:' + responseFromFirst.userCtx.name